# ASP.NET separate web / admin applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, iis-7

I've often developed websites in asp.net webforms with an administration area which is always a folder in the root of the application, where the site also lives. Which will always be compiled into one dll, meaning every small change requires full re-build of a solution - it just doesn't *work* well.

This is quite a lengthy question so my **summary is at the bottom**, but I've tried to give as much information as possible to help.

So at the moment things are set up something like this (you should get the idea):

```
¬ Application Root  
  -  /MyAdminPanel
     - dashboard.aspx
  -  /website-css
     - site.css
  - index.aspx
```

However I've recentley starting developing our sites with ASP.NET MVC and using multiple projects in a solution, like:

```
¬ Solution
  - ClientName.Core
  - ClientName.Models
  - ClientName.CMS.Services
  - ClientName.CMS.Web
  - ClientName.Services
  - ClientName.Web
```

the `.Web` projects being the CMS and front facing websites.

**Is there a better way for me to structure my IIS applications bearing in mind that 99% of the time there will be an administration area for the website?**

There are concerns regarding resources that are uploaded through the administration panel that need to be accessed via the front facing website, so essentially out of the child application and into the root.
This is possibly by doing `Server.MapPath(string path)` as that will go to the root application, however depending on how things were set up, it could potentially not be guaranteed that the root application is where the file needs to go (for instance if both the front and admin facing sites were both in separate virtual applications).
I'm thinking about the situation here if using `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` where the path would actually resolved to the `/MyAdminPanel` child application, which would obviously not be correct.

**Summary**
In essence, to cut a very long story short, an ideal situation would be to have a VS solution as mentioned above, with a similarly structured website (though I am more that happy for this to change to something better), where I can `MapPath` resources to the front facing website and not worry how the website is hosted.

**One thing that is important though is that I can build and maintain the projects separately, as some administration will have different functionality from one client to another**

If you can come up with a much better structure for all of this, I am more than happy to listen! :)

Thanks for taking the time to check this out.

Comment: One thing I've just thought about is still using `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` which would root to the child application, and store the files in the child application, but then just use a virtual directory in the parent application with the same name to map through - hiding it's real location. Or is that going to raise any security concerns?

Comment: Also, looking a bit more I've actually managed to share the compiled code in the child application to use the parent bin compiled code by changing it's code base in the assembly bindings in the child web.config. I've modified my question to remove that element of it.

Comment: The approach I usually take is using areas. I separate the admin from the main site. If you need further separation you could have a ClientName.Web.Common and ClientName.CMS.Web.Common and put your controller logic in there, but I would keep only one Front-End website since that way I can share all resources and scripts and just separate the views using areas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is elegantly simple -- you really only need to worry about mapping 4 paths here -- just write some utility methods that can:

- map a path from the public site http root
- map a path from the public site filesystem root
- map a path from the admin site http root
- map a path from the admin site filesystem root

You'll probably want to make these configuration driven, or at least overridable as this will change in production quickly in scenarios that don't really allow for "rebuild and redeliver software to client" in the timeline.

Comment: Yeah I think I've just been **over**-thinking it a little bit. So you would essentially have an application in IIS, and then have 2 separate virtual applications, one for public site and another for admin site, is that correct? I've got some core functionality that's shared, so I can probably just pass an interface to the methods to do different map paths as you've mentioned.

Comment: I could probably then have the shared compiled code and web.config details within the parent application that could be codebase'd from the child apps config files... or would that be frowned upon?

Comment: I've had much more success using common class libraries and separate app then cascading configurations. Also remember that separate apps is alot more flexible from an operational standpoint. Distinct control panes are awesome.

Comment: Brill, nice one. I'll mark this as the answer as it's cleared my head a bit which is sometimes half the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I've just had a thought about this, how would the bindings work on the web site in IIS if I were to set up a separate app for front and admin? Admin isn't a problem doing www.example.com/admin, but for the front I would not want www.example.com/front - i'd just want to domain to point to the virtual app. Obviously setting the web site physical path to the "front" web files is an option, but then I'm back to square one?

Comment: We just put the admins on a separate, SSL enforced domain. So you get www.example.com for the public site and secure.example.com/admintool for the admin site. Another option is a hard 301 redirect for the root folder -- plenty of apps and big sites do that.

Comment: Sorry, so that would mean that the ssl application (admintool) is still a virtual application of the public website (www.example.com), of which the www.example.com (website) is still the root application. So there is NO virtual application under the website for the public site, only "admintool". Yes? And obviously the secure.example.com and example.com host headers are applied to the IIS "web site" (website)...? basically exactly the same as I'm currently doing it?
The 301 isn't really an option as we'll want to always keep the url clean for SEO.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, you are really looking at totally separate applications, inheriting configurations in .NET can get ugly depending on what you want to change. You could run the admin in the root or in a sub-uri if you choose.